# Woocommerce & Stripe

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I installed woocommerce on a website and to activate card payments I followed Woocommerce suggestions and I settled an account on Stripe as gateway and it was the Express version. Once started with payments I see no transactions list on Stripe Express... there should be a dashboard but I don't see that... plus I read it needs like a week or so to complete payments and see money into destination. So based on your experience I would ask :

1. how I can see full stripe settings and the dashboard?
2. is there a way to speed card payments up because normally card payments needs just max two or three days?
3. eventually is there a better gateway than Stripe which it looks like it has also fees that are a bit expensive?

Thanks to all in advance! :-)
Cheers!

Comment: When you say full stripe settings and dashboard, do you mean on Stripe or for the plugin? You can go to https://dashboard.stripe.com to see transaction data on Stripe. The first payout may take a little longer but the speed of the payout may depend on a lot of factors including the country you're in. 
https://stripe.com/docs/payouts#payout-speed

Comment: Hello @hanzo , first thank you for your answer but since I settled stripe account via woocommerce payments settings and it created a stripe express account...is a stripe express account just a "stripe standard account"?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think Woocommerce creates an Express connected account according to this blog post https://woocommerce.com/document/payments/faq/existing-stripe-account/